# NoReverseMatch Error during template rendering

Tags: python, django

I have this url that causes the error

```
<a href="{% url 'page-two' item_1 item_2 %}">
```

The url should be rendered as */pages/36/some-story*

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('pages/<slug:slug>', views.PageOneView.as_view(), name='page-one'),
        path('pages/<slug:slug_1>/slug:slug_2>', views.PageTwoView.as_view(), name='page-two'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class PageOneView(View):
    def get(self, request, slug):
        run = Pages.objects.get(id=slug)

        item_1 = 36
        item_2 = 'some-story'

        context = {
            'item_1': item_1,
            'item_2': item_2,
        }

        return render(request, "pages/page_1.html", context)


class PageTwoView(View):
    def get(self, request, slug_1, slug_2)
        
        context = {}

        return render(request, "pages/page_2.html", context)
```

The trackback says:

```
Reverse for 'page-two' with arguments '('36', 'some-story')' not found.
```

It seems like the url get's rendered correctly because I see the values I expected. But I still can't figure out where this error is coming from. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

there is a "<" missing before slug:slug_2 in the url pattern

```
path('pages/<slug:slug_1>/slug:slug_2>
```